# Is there any significance of Euler's number other than being the base for the exponential function?

Tags: constants

It seems like most natural situations (that at least I've come across) where Euler's number shows up, there's usually a more general (yet still natural) version of it that contains the exponential function. Even its usual definition as: $$e = \lim_n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
Can be extended to:
$$e^x = \lim_n\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

This seems, at least to me, somewhat unique. Rarely do I find results with other constants like $\pi$ where I can naturally extend them to a consistent family of values like how I can with $e \to e^x$.

Thus the question, does Euler's number have any significance that can't be **naturally** extended to other values of the exponential? Or alternatively, is there any significance to Euler's number other than being equal to $\exp(1)$ or the base of the exponential function?

Note: I realize of course that this isn't really a mathematical question, and that this might not be the appropriate place for this sort of question, if that's indeed the case I will remove this post.

Comment: $|e^{ix}|=1$ for any real x.  $(e^x)'=e^x$.

Comment: The [continued fraction](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/analysis/Lectures/A6.html) for $e$ follows a very simple pattern and I can't see how that naturally extends to arbitrary powers of $e$. (Correction: actually, it does extend in a way see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula].)

Comment: An alternative definition of $e$ underlies its especially nice derivative formula. The number is $e$ is the unique base $b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that  
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{b^x - 1}{x} = 1.
$$

Comment: @herbsteinberg I mean, as I wrote in my post I'd call that a property of the exponential function rather than Euler's number itself. The only real importance to Euler's number in those cases is that it can be used as the base of the exponential function under usual notation, take the notation away and those properties disappear.

Comment: @SammyBlack while I can't really argue with that exactly. I'd also like to point out that you can also give it a meaning in the exponential that is:

The exponential function is the unique function of the form $b^x$ such that $b^x-1$ is asymptotically equal to $x$ as $x \to 0$. In fact this statement is much more useful than the original meaning.

Comment: $\frac{1}{e}$ comes up in some probability questions. For example the Secretary problem (See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)

Comment: @Fishbane that counts as an answer doesn't it?

Comment: @SuzuHirose If you want to add some more info and write it as an answer, that is fine, I probably won't be. It's mostly up to the original asker to decide if something works.

Comment: Other than its name, what are you questioning?